# Render a conditional form element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a select (aka picklist) field on a form . Based on its value, it affects the next field (dependent field), which is either: another select, input type text, or disabled input.

The pseudocode

```
// based on a state value, leadField, determine valueField

// if leadField === null, return a disabled input
// else, go through the array of leadField values

// if a leadFieldValue === leadField
// then go through leadFieldValue

// if leadFieldValue.pickListValues is not empty
// render the select options
// else render an input type text
```

The code

```
  renderValueField() {
    if(this.state.leadField === null) {
            return <input type="text" id="input1" className="slds-input" disable/>
    } else {
      return this.props.territoryCriteriaFields.map((criteriaField) => {
        const shouldRender = criteriaField.name === this.state.leadField;
        if (shouldRender) {
          if (typeof criteriaField.pickListValues !== 'undefined' && criteriaField.pickListValues.length > 0) {
            return criteriaField.picklistValues.map((option) => {
                return (
                  <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                );
            });
          } else {
            return <input type="text" id="input1" className="slds-input" />
          }
        } 
      });      
    }
  }
```

My problem: when I call the above `{this.renderValueField}` on the page,  it needs to be between `<select>`'s
when `pickListValues !== null`, like so

```
<select>
 {this.renderValueField()}
</select>
```

but I need the `<selects>`'s to not be there if an input is rendered.

tl;dr - conditionally add remove the `<select>` tags, depending on the return values of my `renderValueField()`

Comment: In your `render()` function, call `var rVF = this.renderValueField();`, check its value, then return `<select>{rVF}</select>` or something else.

Comment: @ChrisG how do I compare its return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `<option>`s in a `<select>` inside the function:

```
renderValueField() {
  if(this.state.leadField === null) {
    return <input type="text" id="input1" className="slds-input" disable/>
  } else {
    return this.props.territoryCriteriaFields.map((criteriaField) => {
      const shouldRender = criteriaField.name === this.state.leadField;
      if (shouldRender) {
        if (typeof criteriaField.pickListValues !== 'undefined' && criteriaField.pickListValues.length > 0) {
          return (
            <select>
              {criteriaField.picklistValues.map((option) => {
                return (
                  <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
          );
        } else {
          return <input type="text" id="input1" className="slds-input" />
        }
      } 
    });      
  }
}
```